# Getting text of buttons from an Activity and setting it as text in Text View in other Activity

Tags: java, android

I m working on a project i have two categories Cricketers and Animals on one activity as Button and a Text View on other activity i want to change the text of Text View when ever i presses the Button i.e If Cricketer then set text to cricketer same goes for animal.

OnClick Listner for both buttons: On Activity 1

```
public void onClickcricketer(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this,offlineQuestionsession.class);
    final Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btncricket);
    String crickettext = b.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra("Cricket",crickettext);
    startActivity(i);
}
public void onClickanimal(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this,offlineQuestionsession.class);

    final Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnanimal);
    String animaltext = b.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra("Animal",animaltext);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Code on Activity 2:

```
Bundle cricketData = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (cricketData == null){
        return;
    }
    String Cricket = cricketData.getString("Cricket");
    final TextView c = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCategryShow);
    c.setText(Cricket);

    Bundle AnimalData = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (AnimalData == null){
        return;
    }
    String Animal = AnimalData.getString("Animal");
    final TextView a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCategryShow);
    a.setText(Animal);
```

This method just show animal text in Text view.. when i click Crcketer button it shows nothing

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted thus far, and where you are finding an issue

Comment: post code where you set text in TextView in another activity.

Answer (score 1):

First perform an onClick method:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String toExtra = "" + btn.getText();
                Intent i = new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("key",toExtra);
            }
        });
```

then in the new Activity OnCreate method add:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String fromExtra = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

and finally setText to your TextView:

```
txt.setText(fromExtra)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is doing correct, see your code again, On same TextView you are setting text Animal which is null in case of clicking cricket ..

Try this in second activity:

```
 String Cricket = getIntent().getStringExtra("KEY");
 final TextView c = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCategryShow);
 c.setText(Cricket);
```

And make your methods like this:

```
public void onClickcricketer(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this,YourNewActivity.class);
    final Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.txv_cricket);
    String crickettext = b.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra("KEY",crickettext);
    startActivity(i);
}
public void onClickanimal(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this,YourNewActivity.class);

    final Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.txv_animal);
    String animaltext = b.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra("KEY", animaltext);
    startActivity(i);
}
```